# I have to removed or hide this text in woocommerce "Sorry, no products matched your selection. Please choose a different combination."

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I wanted to remove or hide this line in woocommerce "Sorry, no products matched your selection. Please choose a different combination." in product variation

Answer (score 0):

You can use snippet below in your **functions.php** file.

```
function woo_custom_ajax_variation_threshold( $qty, $product ) {
    return 50;
}       
add_filter( 'woocommerce_ajax_variation_threshold', 'woo_custom_ajax_variation_threshold', 10, 2 );
```